# Install an application in one computer but run it in another

Tags: windows

I was trying to install an application it wouldn't work but after asking about it turned out to be 16-bit though the application says it’s a win32 executable.

I was wondering what if I install this program on one computer, where its compatible, but run that same application on another computer without having it installed.

In simple words installing an software in a compatible Windows copy but running it in an incompatible copy of Windows without installing its components.

If it dosen't make sense lets say I have one computer and want to install something but unexpectedly to find out its uncompatible I setup a whole new computer just to install it but I have more application that may not run on it. What I want is to use the new machines I setup to use its computing power to run the software but I use it on my own system without connect to it remotley via anything.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Are you asking if two copies of the same software can be installed on different machines? Are you worried about licensing? Just run it where it works.

Comment: No i'm asking if theres a way to run an application in 1 computer but all the all interface stuff of what happens when it opens on anthor computer

Comment: Makes utterly no sense. Why not do it all on one machine?

Comment: As some of the applications don't work in one machine and some do it would be very inconvienent for me switching machines all the time just to run some applications

Comment: That’s what remote terminal clients are for. Why not use VNC from one machine to another?

Comment: Still inconvenient if I can have all the applications in one machine and connect vis remote terminal wouldn't it be better then setting up 3 diffrent machines and connecting to them when needed to?

Comment: That’s what virtual machines are for.

Comment: to setup 3 vmware and connect to it 1 by 1 is still inconvenient if everything is on 1 server or machine wouldn't it be better then setting up the other 3?

Comment: Is it definitely the application that is 16-bit and not the installer file? If it's the installer and the app itself is 32-bit there are ways to extract the app files such that it can then be installed on a newer machine (have had to do it previously with an old 32-bit that was packaged in a 16-bit installer).

Comment: When installing the application with winevdm its working fine its 16 bit, but when running the files with winevdm it says that they are a win32 excutable, but yet they don't open

Comment: Is winedvm not saying that its win32 executable, just because it has .exe as extension?

Comment: I did not understand could you explain what you meant?

Comment: In explorer, if you look at the type of a file, the file extension (.xxx) will be given a name. For example, .pdf has the name: Portable Document Format, or PDF-File, depending on what PDF viewer you use. An .exe file can have the text "Program", or "Executable" or even "32-bit executable" written there. The reason to add 32-bit could be that it also has .com for 16-bit executable, which is technically incorrect. In this case the win32 is misleading and could also be given to a 64-bit windows application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 16-bit program is structured with a different layout than a 32-bit program is.

Whereas some OSses can understand 16-bit and 32-bit programs, others can understand 32-bit and 64 bit.

Do note that support for 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit all come down to the architecture of the CPU. If the CPU supports one or more of these, it can run programs that support this natively, and the OS must then also be able to run them.

Most modern CPU's which are 64-bit will have a 32-bit abstraction layer too, but support for 16-bit has been removed a long time ago.

So in order to natively run a 16-bit program, you need a CPU and an OS that both run this architecture.

If you don't have either, then emulation is going to be the only way.

Installing the program on another machine will not change the fact that your CPU, the device that actually executes the program, will not magically understand the different layout.

Comment: Could you tell me what OS and CPU is required for 16bits to work perfectly normal aswell us support for mordern softwares?

Comment: None. 16-bit is the era with Pentium 1 and windows 2000 was the latest OS that supported 16-bit. You will need emulation. A virtual machine or maybe even DosBox-X which can run Windows 98, depending on what hardware you have.

Comment: So it is impossible for me to run 16bit applications on mordern hardware? apart from using vm/dosbox

Comment: Natively, yes. Inside a virtual machine, sure it will work.

Comment: @LPChip:  Disregard my previous comment, I thought you were referring to the latest Windows with NTVDM.

Comment: @OskarSkog well technically, until Windows XP SP2, it also featured 16-bit support

Comment: You can run 16-bit applications on 32-bit versions of Windows. That of course eliminates the possibility of running Windows 11 since it’s only 64-bit

Comment: @Ramhound more investigation turns up that it is possible to install NTVDM to create an emulation layer to activate 16-bit support on 32-bit versions. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LPChip - I am confused, I found 3 duplicates that suggest the only version of Windows that cannot run 16-bit applications is a 64-bit version of Windows, that’s been my understanding for 20 years that it’s due to how a 64-bit operating system boots and must enable a processor mode. If Windows XP supported 16-bit applications then I see no reason that Windows 7 32-bit also didn’t have that capability considering it was built in the same NT kernel. 32-bit Windows had an emulation layer for 16-bit applications but that was impossible to provide on 64-bit, likewise, 32-bit was added due to WoW64

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, my mind is a bit of a mess, too much stuff going on. I read it somewhere, but can't find it. I did also read a lot of posts stating that only 64-bit doesn't work, but others saying that you need NTVDM for it to work. I lost track of how and what myself.

Comment: It appears that NTVDM is no longer included **by default**, at least on Home edition: https://oskog97.com/sshin/ntvdm/  Why isn't it dead yet?